# MDX query date range

Tags: mdx, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am working pentaho dashboard trying to generate report to get transaction count per day between two date. i am beginner to mdx query below query shows only two date transaction count what i want is range between. i know it how to do it on simple query

SQL Working Query

```
SELECT
    DATE(modified) AS trndate,
    COUNT(id)
FROM
    log.transaction
   WHERE  DATE(modified) BETWEEN DATE(${from_date}) AND DATE(${to_date})

GROUP BY
     trndate
```

MDX Query which shows only two date transaction instead i want range between two date

```
WITH
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[created].[2014-10-01 12:01:53.507787], [created].[2014-10-01 20:34:14.410064]}
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[id]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [transaction]
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can use a colon to specify a range

```
WITH
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[created].[2014-10-01 12:01:53.507787]:[created].[2014-10-01 20:34:14.410064]}
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[id]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [transaction]
```

Comment: hi whytheq thanks , I have tried this query earlier but it will require exact match of start date if i tried with start date like this '2014-10-01 00:00:00.00' it does not show records  and my date format will be yyyy-mm-dd and format in sql is  '2014-10-01 12:01:53.507787'

Comment: and i want count between two days week wise/day wise/month wise how i can achieve this currently it shows one count because time vary

Comment: Can you modify tables and/or cube definition? I guess, your cube would be much easier to use, if you'd add more levels to your time hierarchy (like Year -> Month -> Day of month -> Time, or at least like Date -> Time). In this case you should be able to use range as whytheq suggested, using the dates without the time part. Note: to use ranges you'd likely want your time dimension to be continuous at date level (every date starting from some date should be present in your dim_date table, even if there are no facts associated with some dates).

Comment: @user4637357 hey thanks . i will  give it to try.can we not do it like normal query **WHERE  DATE(created) BETWEEN DATE(${from_date}) AND DATE(${to_date})**

Comment: @Sagar: you can apply `filter` function to the set, which forms your rows, but I am not sure how to write the conditions for date values. You can try to treat date members as strings and use smth. like this: `SET [~ROWS] AS
    Filter([created].DefaultMember.Children, [created].CurrentMember.name >= "2014-10-01" AND Left([created].CurrentMember.Name, 10) <= "2014-10-01")`. The `Left(x, 10)` function should take the date part as a substring. Sorry, my MDX is quite rusty and I don't have possibility to test it ATM.

Comment: @user4637357: thanks this worked.how can i put group by clause on it for getting days/week/month wise transaction count between two dates

Comment: @Sagar this is now a new question

Comment: @whytheq: Created new question please look
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204929/how-to-apply-group-by-on-mdx-query)