# How to Apply group by on mdx Query

Tags: mdx, pentaho, pentaho-cde

Working pentaho dashboard trying to generate report to get transaction count per day/Week/Month between two date.

**Below MDX Query return transaction count 1 because 'created' is not group by**

```
WITH
SET [~COLUMNS] AS Filter([created].DefaultMember.Children, [created].CurrentMember.name >= "2014-10-01" AND Left([created].CurrentMember.Name, 10) <= "2014-10-02")
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[markup].[markup].Members}
SELECT
NON EMPTY CrossJoin([~COLUMNS], {[Measures].[Transaction Count]}) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [transaction]
```

How to i can group column '[created]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just move the measure into the WHERE clause:

```
WITH
SET [~COLUMNS] AS Filter([created].DefaultMember.Children, [created].CurrentMember.name >= "2014-10-01" AND Left([created].CurrentMember.Name, 10) <= "2014-10-02")
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[markup].[markup].Members}
SELECT
NON EMPTY [~COLUMNS] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [transaction]
WHERE [Measures].[Transaction Count]
```

Comment: Same output not count day wise/week/month [Please see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qwoY.png)

Comment: You need to then change your created dimension so that it includes hierarchies for week, month, year etc

Comment: Check out the Date dimension in Microsoft’s Adventure Works cube...I think that sort of design for Date would cover lots of eventualities